# How to fix PageViewController in specific view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

I want to fix PageViewController views in specific view. When i load into ViewController main view it's working fine, but when i load it in subView PageViewController not fixing in that subView. How to fix PageViewController in subview.

Image 1, red colour view is ,my subView I want to fix PageViewController in this red colour view.

[image]

image 2 , this is I'm getting.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by fix it? Does it refer to constraints?

Comment: @ PGDev, I want to fix size of PageViewController in subView. This is my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801714/in-pageviewcontroller-navigation-not-working

Comment: @iOS - in the code in your other question, you are calling `pageControllerView.addSubview(pageContainer.view)` ... but you are not setting the frame and/or constraints on `pageContainer.view`. You need to do so, in order to match its "page views" to the size of your (red) subview.

Comment: @  DonMag, how to fix constraints in **pageContainer.view** can you please give small example for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code in your other question, you are adding your page view to your (red) subview but not setting its frame.

```
    // Create the page container
    pageContainer = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    pageContainer.delegate = self
    pageContainer.dataSource = self
    pageContainer.setViewControllers([page1], direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

    // Add it to the view
    pageControllerView.addSubview(pageContainer.view)

    // set the frame of the pageContainer view to match its superview (the red view)
    pageContainer.view.frame = pageControllerView.bounds
    // let it resize if needed (such as device rotation)
    pageContainer.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

This *should* solve the issue.

Comment: @ DonMag, one more new question, can you please answer it. How to set navigation bar back button text. I'm unable to change back btn text . my code is

Comment: let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
                backItem.title = "Call Log"
                self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
                if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                    backItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Exo2-Medium", size: 20)!], for: UIControl.State.normal);
                } else {
                    backItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Exo2-Medium", size: 15)!], for: UIControl.State.normal);
                }