# UIPageViewController change navigation bar back button title

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

This is my complete code . [In PageViewController navigation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801714/in-pageviewcontroller-navigation-not-working)

Here when I click button in view controller of page view controller , it will navigate to next view (Final View Controller). Now i want to change the navigation bar back button .

[image]

See in above image when i click button in ViewController [View controller will load in PageViewController] it will navigate to FinalViewController

My code for navigation bar title ViewController:

```
@IBAction func btn(_ sender: Any) {
    print("ViewController one")
    print(variable)

    let storyboard = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FVC")
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = "Final VC"
    //        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem

    (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.self.navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem = backItem

    (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.pushViewController(storyboard!, animated: true)


}
```

But this code not working

Comment: Is the `FinalController` also a part of `PageViewController`?

Comment: @ PGDev, no this is separate view controller

Comment: FinalController is independent view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer working fine...

```
let storyboard = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FVC")
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem()
backButton.title = "name"
(UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.self.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = backButton
(UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.pushViewController(storyboard!, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The back button belongs to the previous view controller, not the one currently presented on screen.
you can use delegate or segue 
see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471164/how-to-set-back-button-text-in-swift/32284525#32284525)

Comment: I write my code in ViewController of PageViewController , because I'm clicking button in ViewController of PageViewController, Now it's navigate to FinalViewController. That is separate ViewController .

Comment: As I told, make a delegate method from your separate view controller to your view controller of Page View Controller and after click update your back button